# Space between border and content? / Border distance from content?

Tags: css

Is it possible to increase the distance between a border and its content?
If it is possible, just do it on here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4UAp/2/)

What I plan on doing is putting a glow around the content (using a shadow with 0px/0px distance) and then putting a border a couple of pixels away from the glow.

**NOTE: I have decided to do an inset shadow and a border instead, it looks better, but thanks for the answers :3**

Comment: Realizing this is pretty old... Even if you went with a solution that rendered the [question moot](http://www.maniacworld.com/question-is-moot.html) to you, it's worth accepting an answer if it answered that original question satisfactorily.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add padding. Padding the element will increase the space between its content and its border. However, note that a box-shadow will begin *outside* the *border*, not the content, meaning you can't put space between the shadow and the box. Alternatively you could use :before or :after pseudo selectors on the element to create a slightly bigger box that you place the shadow on, like so: http://jsbin.com/aqemew/edit#source

Answer (score 10):

Its possible using pseudo element (after).
I have added to the original code a

```
position:relative
```

and some margin.
Here is the modified JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4UAp/86/

```
#content{
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-style: ridge;
  border-color: #567498;
  border-spacing:10px;
  position:relative;
  background:#000;
}
#content:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  border: red 2px solid;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? I mean why keeping `position: relative` in `#content` and `position: absolute` in `#content:after` leads to this effect?

Answer (score 8):

If you have background on that element, then, adding padding would be useless.

So, in this case, you can use [background-clip: content-box;](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-clip&preval=content-box) or [outline-offset](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_outline-offset.asp)

Explanation:
If you use wrapper, then it would be simple to separate the background from border. But if you want to style the same element, which has a background, no matter how much padding you would add, there would be no space between background and border, unless you use **background-clip** or **outline-offset**

Answer (score 4):

You usually use padding to add distance between a border and a content.[However](http://jsfiddle.net/r4UAp/5/), background are spread on padding.

You can still do it with [nested element](http://jsfiddle.net/r4UAp/6/).

```css
.outer {
  border-style: ridge;
  border-color: #567498;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(39, 54, 73)), color-stop(1, rgb(30, 42, 54)));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center bottom, rgb(39, 54, 73) 0%, rgb(30, 42, 54) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap another div around it, which has the border and the padding you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an`<hr>`and styling that. Its a minimal markup change but seems to need less css so that might do the trick.

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BhxsZ/