# How to get a partial circle border around an image?

Tags: html, css

I want to design the following for displaying profile picture. I tried using `border-style: dashed`, but that's not what I want; I want only three lines (dashes) in the border. How can I accomplish this?

Here's what I tried:

```css
#circle {
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px dashed;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <div id="circle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The effect I desire:

[image: profile picture]

Comment: Have you consider to use a background image?

Comment: I think I found partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34135723/4688321). But, I want only 3 dashes in the border. Can anybody suggest any ways?

Comment: @Sfili_81, no I didn't consider that but wanna avoid using background image unless there is absolutely no solution possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea with multiple background:

```css
#circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid transparent; /* Control the thickness*/
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/100/200/200) center/cover content-box,
    
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) top         /100% 20% border-box,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom left /35%  50% border-box,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom right/35%  50% border-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

If you want space between image and border add an extra layer:

```css
#circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid transparent; /*Control the thickness*/
  padding:3px; /*control the space*/
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/100/200/200) center/cover content-box,
    linear-gradient(white,white) padding-box,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) top         /100% 20% border-box,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom left /35%  50% border-box,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom right/35%  50% border-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting implementation to make a "T" cut-out and hide it with the background image :-) Reminds me of Mr Terrific from DC Comics.

Comment: I am really not able to understand what is going on in the `background` property. Can you please explain?

Comment: @kiner_shah it's a multiple background layer. the image on the top and 3 on the bottom ... the 2 on the bottom are simple rectangle where I specify the size and the position

Comment: @TylerH ah, let's hope Mr Terrific don't catch me for plagiarism :p

Comment: Can you explain `100% 20%` in second image?

Comment: @kiner_shah it's the size, each layer is having `position/size` ... so the that layer is on the top with a width=100% and height=20%

Comment: @kiner_shah I advise you to adjust the different value and see what is happening, you will then easily get the trick

Comment: Yeah, I am trying now!

Comment: Ahhh, I get it now! They are rectangles (if I remove border-radius) located at top, bottom left and bottom right! Part of them was hidden by the main image! Nice one that is! But, I also want some blank space between border and the image, is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: @kiner_shah I am updating ;)

Answer (score 2):

I tried something like that, not sure if entirely fit your needs..but give it a try, maybe it's a good starting point for you.  Play with the numbers from `css` file and maybe you got exactly what you need.

Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-glade-uo7bg

```css
.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}

#shadow-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 -4px blue;
}

#shadow-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -2.5px;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 5px -5px 0 -4px blue;
}

#shadow-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -4px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 0 -4px blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello Circle!</h1>
<div>
  <div class="circle">
  <div id="shadow-1"></div>
  <div id="shadow-2"></div>
  <div id="shadow-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good solution, however I want the border of same thickness. But, that is giving me some intuition about the solution which I will try.